# how to calculate and print the cog of object in opencv using python?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I have converted an image into a binary image making the object of my desired color as white and rest as black.

How can I proceed from here?

How to calculate the cog of the image and print it?

Comment: please explain 'cog' .

Comment: ah, ok. have a look at [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments)  and findContours() then.